# Expression result unused objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am about as nooby to this as it gets.
Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{    
    int sum;   
    sum = 50 + 25;
    "The sum of 50 and 25 is %i", sum ;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the line:

```
"The sum of 50 and 25 is %i", sum ;
```

to:

```
printf( "The sum of 50 and 25 is %i", sum );
```

The line in quotes by itself is a syntax error that just happens to be getting by the compiler (which is apparently throwing a warning instead).

Comment: Actually, it's not a syntax error. It's an expression using the comma operator. That simply evaluates each expression separated by commas in order and the value of the comma expression as a whole is the value of the last subexpression (`sum` in this case). It is legal in C for an expression to be a statement unto itself. (That's what `sum = 50 + 25;` is, for example.) Since the first subexpression of the comma operator (a string literal) has no side effects, that line is equivalent to `sum;`, which is legal but strange because nothing is using the value and it has no side effects. So it warns.

Answer (score 0):

You have this warning because of not using your sum value. To print it use NSLog

Comment: This would normally be a correct answer, but the O.P. appears to be using straight C and not Objective C